# Is anyone facing data loss issues in iOS using parse sdk?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, data-loss

Facing data loss when saving offline PFObjects. We have objects that point to other objects, on saving one object sometimes the child object gets lost.

Comment: If you can share some code and/or more details, it will be easier for someone to help you.

Comment: 1. We have a class having column type array of pointers, while saving the class from iOS app, sometimes the array of pointers are not saved.

2. The method used to save the class is saveInBackground

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using to save these objects?